# Which DNS Server should I point at?

Tags: domain-name-system, router

**INFO:**
My Cisco UFB Router has 2 DNS entries in the WAN settings, I assume Primary and Secondary.
Similarly my MAC allows for multiple entries, and seems to pick up the 2 from the router, unless I config manually.
Obviously I can auto configure or manually configure either router or computer.
My ISP provides me 2 x DNS Addresses. e.g. 123.132.231.213 & 123.132.231.214
Great!

**THE PROBLEM:**
Both of my ISPs DNS Servers stopped performing at the same time today. Not providing DNS records for a typical website, giving me an error "... X server DNS address could not be found. ..."
So I am thinking what is the point of having 2 DNS Servers from the same company.
My ISP typically has a quicker response time than Google 8.8.8.8 so It makes sense to use my ISP.

**MY QUESTIONS:**
Should I use my ISPs Primary DNS, and then Googles as a secondary? Or stick with both ISP DNS entries?

**What configuration should I use in my router?**
**What configuration should I use in my computer?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely use ISP as the first DNS entry, as that lets you take advantage of local / national caches.

Second entry should probably be ISP, but if both fail at the same time then that's pointless. You could put Google in there.

Some routers allow more than two DNS server entries. The windows advanced TCP settings (control panel -> network adapter properties -> tcp4 -> advanced -> dns) also allows you to add more DNS servers even if you're using DHCP, I assume you could add Google DNS in there. To play it safe I'd probably enter ISP DNS at the top, in case it overrides the DCHP, then Google underneath.

[image: Windows 10 DNS]